# Any way to make apt-get more like yum visually?

Tags: apt, package-management, yum

When installing/removing packages using yum, you will get a nice tabular summary before proceeding. While "apt-get" just returns some plain text.

Personally I found the yum implementation way more intuitive and pragmatical. Is there any way to bring this good presentation of yum to distros which don't have it?

Here you will see an example of the output of "yum" and "apt/apt-get" package managers:

```
root@ee754c0c349c:/# apt install nano
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  spell
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nano
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
Need to get 231 kB of archives.
After this operation, 778 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 nano amd64 2.9.3-2 [231 kB]
Fetched 231 kB in 3s (92.0 kB/s)
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Selecting previously unselected package nano.
(Reading database ... 4046 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nano_2.9.3-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nano (2.9.3-2) ...
Setting up nano (2.9.3-2) ...
update-alternatives: using /bin/nano to provide /usr/bin/editor (editor) in auto mode
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/editor.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/nano.1.gz (of link group editor) doesn't exist
update-alternatives: using /bin/nano to provide /usr/bin/pico (pico) in auto mode
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/pico.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/nano.1.gz (of link group pico) doesn't exist
```

and

```
    [root@5c561c79e101 /]# yum install nano
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C.UTF-8
Last metadata expiration check: 0:06:18 ago on Mon Apr 13 12:58:08 2020.
Dependencies resolved.
===============================================================================================
 Package            Architecture         Version                    Repository            Size
===============================================================================================
Installing:
 nano               x86_64               2.9.8-1.el8                BaseOS               581 k

Transaction Summary
===============================================================================================
Install  1 Package

Total size: 581 k
Installed size: 2.2 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
[SKIPPED] nano-2.9.8-1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded
warning: /var/cache/dnf/BaseOS-f6a80ba95cf937f2/packages/nano-2.9.8-1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 8483c65d: NOKEY
CentOS-8 - Base                                                1.6 MB/s | 1.6 kB     00:00
Importing GPG key 0x8483C65D:
 Userid     : "CentOS (CentOS Official Signing Key) <security@centos.org>"
 Fingerprint: 99DB 70FA E1D7 CE22 7FB6 4882 05B5 55B3 8483 C65D
 From       : /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-centosofficial
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Key imported successfully
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded.
Running transaction
  Preparing        :                                                                       1/1
  Installing       : nano-2.9.8-1.el8.x86_64                                               1/1
  Running scriptlet: nano-2.9.8-1.el8.x86_64                                               1/1
  Verifying        : nano-2.9.8-1.el8.x86_64                                               1/1

Installed:
  nano-2.9.8-1.el8.x86_64

Complete!
```

Comment: I think I understand: you would like a neatly formatted table resuming what has happened. No, as far as I know no Debian tool provides that. I know about `apt-get`, `aptitude` and `apt`, and all provide a similar output. Maybe you could post a bug marked as a wishlist to `apt`, and request a nicely-formatted tabular output similar to yum's.

Answer (score 0):

Any update on this? I'm migrating from CentOS to Ubuntu and this APT (tho it is fast, nice and easy to use) gives me the shivers and not in a good way. It is terrible to review anything in it before installing any application or executing any other task. :(